# How can I redirect Sphinx warnings to stdout but keep errors in stderr

Tags: python, stdout, python-sphinx, stderr

In Sphinx build, all the warnings and errors are written in `stderr`. However, I want only error written in `stderr` and warnings written in `stdout`.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: That's kind of a strange requirement. stdout is for the program's result (with the idea that it can be parsed by the next program in the pipeline) and stderr is for anything that's not a part of it. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for your help. In my runtime environment, content written into stderr will trigger a failure. I don't want warning message trigger the failure and only error should do.

Comment: Then maybe it's rather your environment that needs patching. As per my previous message, [output on `stderr` does not automatically mean a fatal error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr)). Perhaps your sentinel could use a user-supplied regex to detect error/non-error messages.

Comment: Alternatively, your environment seems to be designed with the idea in mind to treat warnings as errors, which is a valid and justified mindset for use in domains with high reliability requirements like kernel drivers and embedded systems (and CPython pull requests :) ). So, to be in line with it, you should not ignore warnings but right on the contrary: direct `sphinx` to treat them as errors. After all, a `sphinx` warning means that something in the resulting documentation won't work.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be changed unless you load `sphinx` as a package and monkey-patch its machinery:

`sphinx\cmdline.py`:

```
<...>
def main(argv=sys.argv[1:]):
<...>
    status = sys.stdout
    warning = sys.stderr
    error = sys.stderr

    if args.quiet:
        status = None

    if args.really_quiet:
        status = warning = None

    if warning and args.warnfile:
        try:
            warnfp = open(args.warnfile, 'w')
        <...>
        warning = Tee(warning, warnfp)  # type: ignore
        error = warning

    <...>
        with patch_docutils(), docutils_namespace():
            app = Sphinx(srcdir, confdir, outdir, doctreedir, args.builder,
                         confoverrides, status, warning, args.freshenv,
                         args.warningiserror, args.tags, args.verbosity, args.jobs)
            app.build(args.force_all, filenames)
            return app.statuscode
```

As you can see, `Sphinx` doesn't even have a separate constructor argument for errors vs warnings.